# Categories of questions

Tags: discussion

The following categories of questions are as follows:

#### newest     featured     faq     votes     active     unanswered

Why can't there be subcategories for each of these categories? 

i.e. "The newest unanswered question"

If this is a duplicate, I apologize.

Comment: You can click [UNANSWERED](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and then sort them by `newest`. SE will remember your preference. And here is a [direct link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)

Comment: @5pm Thanks I will try to do that.

Comment: @5PM please go ahead and post this as an answer, I will accept it so that the question can be over with.

Comment: Interestingly enough I read "Calories of questions" and I wondered if that's the first step into a diet of MSE. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Category theory = calorie theory? "Double cheeseburger" is a morphism from "healthy" to "overweight", but the inverse morphism is much longer...

Comment: @Rahul: I suppose I'm terminal object in that category. I don't gain weight... I lose it. Regardless to my diet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: [such an option already exists](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest).